# Include phone frame in snapshot in Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm developing an app and I'm using Android Emulator to get some snapshots.

By default, the screen is captured without the phone frame, like this:

[image]

but I'd like to add the phone frame, like this (I captured the screen using the Mac built-in screen capture)

[image]

How can I do that? I could use the Mac screen capture but then I would have to crop the images, resizing them etc..etc..)

Comment: reason for -1 ?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I also had this question so I upvoted. All's now right in the world.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By design, the Android Emulator just takes the full resolution of the app screen. If you want the device screen, take the screenshot from Android Studio.  See this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot.html

Inside of Android Studio, you can add and remove the screen, screen glare, and some additional cropping options.

[image: Android Studio Screenshot tool]

Comment: Can I do this in VS Code as well?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the emulator without Android Studio, you can use this web tool by google to add device frames to the screenshots:

https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/device-art-generator

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT click on the camera icon next to the device.  That emulates taking a screenshot using the device to itself. (i.e. power and volume down on a physical device.)

Go to Android Studio itself and then:

`cmd+shift+p` > `Screen Capture`!

[image]

Surprisingly, it's a different thing and gives you the frame.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you change the mode
Click on the emulator
Press Ctrl + Z on Windows machine to change the mode
Press again for vise versa, not sure about macs

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **Expo**, the other answers will not help you, as Expo projects cannot be opened in Android Studio.

However, I found this article with instructions to get around this problem: [Include a phone frame in a screenshot of an Android Expo project](https://dev.to/tylerlwsmith/include-a-phone-frame-in-a-screenshot-of-an-android-expo-project-2602).

It worked for me!

Also, I found an alternative for frame-less screenshots: [Device art generator](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/device-art-generator), though it is limited to Google's devices (Pixel, Nexus, etc.), and I found the fit between frame and screenshot not to be perfect, even if the screenshot was generated with exactly the same model (i.e. same screen dimensions) as the one used in the web page.